# How to build a Unity project as HoloLens object with default UI?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

Whenever I launch an Unity project on the HoloLens it runs in some kind of "fullscreen" mode and hides all other objects placed in space. However, the preinstalled demo objects (the spaceship and the puppet for example) may be placed in space with other objects and also provide a HoloLens UI by default (for scaling, rotating and translating the object).

How can I export an Unity project so it already provides the default HoloLens UI and can coexist with other objects?

Comment: You cannot currently use holograms in the shell like some of the demo apps are doing. The API is limited. You can have 2D apps as tiles using the xaml export setting and those will open in the shell along other 2D apps, or you have to build your app as 3D and it will take over the whole view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You can't

At least, not right now.

This is a limitation on the current level of API access the HoloLens SDK allows.  Creating holograms is just not something we can do yet. Microsoft can because they are able to work at a deeper level, running natively built code that interacts directly with the HoloLens OS.  It's a demonstration of what the hardware *can do* not what developers have been *given access to.*  Or in the case of Unity, what the Unity team has provided access to. For example, Spatial Understanding is not part of the VR or WSA UnityEngine packages. Instead, the HoloToolkit is available to [provide a C# wrapper around the underlying C++ dll](https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/SpatialUnderstanding/Scripts/SpatialUnderstandingDll.cs#L365).

Also, in addition to what @Everts said in the comments:

> You cannot currently use holograms in the shell like some of the demo apps are doing. The API is limited. You can have 2D apps as tiles using the xaml export setting and those will open in the shell along other 2D apps, or you have to build your app as 3D and it will take over the whole view.

There are other limitations as well, such as the inability to print from the HoloLens. Microsoft has these limitations [documented](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/current_limitations_for_apps_using_apis_from_the_shell) and support for these features is being worked on, they just aren't currently available or will have unpredictable behavior.  It appears that Microsoft's goal will be to support them eventually, but there are no details as to when, so it is possible that full support will never be available.

Additionally, the code used to position holograms in space isn't available *either.*  That is, if you want to have a cube in your full-screen app that you drag around and reposition, you've got to write the collision-against-the-real-world code yourself. It's clear that Microsoft has gone to great lengths to make it look nice for their holograms...but hasn't exposed it for developers.

Nor is an on-screen keyboard supported in full screen applications. I'm not kidding and the "best" workaround I've seen is creating a *second* 2D xmal application that you switch to for the builtin keyboard and then switch back (and no instruction on how to actually *do* this in Unity).  So I'll be wrestling with a VR keyboard off the asset store.

I also haven't found any information one way or another about how to *style* the 2D shell window that you get when you do have a 3D full screen app (you get it when booting the app from the start menu, rather than when debugging through Visual Studio).  It just displays as a blank white default texture, which is rather annoying to look at (if not outright painful).  It would be nice to have the API hooks to give it a 3D icon the way Robo Raid and Learn Gestures does, but I'd be willing to settle for a simple texture in the meantime.  But even that, I think, isn't a supported API hook yet. Or if it is, I can't find any information on it.

So yeah, at the current time, there are a lot of things developers simply *cannot do* with the HoloLens. We just have to wait for Microsoft to develop the technology further and expose more tools. Or write them ourselves.